# American in Schengen - multiple visits over the year

Tags: schengen, us-citizens, visa-free-entry, 90-180-visa-rules, repeat-visits

One calculation question…
I’m an American on a Schengen 90/180 day tourist visa.
I was in Oslo, Norway from Jan 9 - March 19.
My plan is to go back from…
May 15 - May 27, 2019.
Then again July 1st - Sept 1, 2019. 
Then again Dec 1, 2019 - Feb 28, 2020.

Is that all legal and ok Schengen visa-wise?
I don’t go over the 90 days in 180 day sliding ruler do I?

Thank you so much!

Comment: You can check your status using the calculator [here](https://ec.europa.eu/assets/home/visa-calculator/calculator.htm?lang=en)

Answer (score 2):

As you can see from the [Schengen calculator](https://ec.europa.eu/assets/home/visa-calculator/calculator.htm?lang=en), you will not exceed the 90/180 limitation with this plan, but your last stay is exactly 90 days, so you may want to give yourself a buffer in case of flight delays or other unforseen circumstances.  You don't need to reschedule your flights to do that.  Instead, you can spend one or more entire days in a non-Schengen country.

Comment: Even though the planned stays won’t breach the 90/180 day rule, is there a possibility that Immigration would question the purpose of such frequent and lengthy visits (all to Norway, it seems, and around 177 days in total in 2019) at some point?